# Fastest image iteration in Python

Tags: python, optimization, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I am creating a simple green screen app with Python 2.7.4 but am getting quite slow results. I am currently using PIL 1.1.7 to load and iterate the images and saw huge speed-ups changing from the old getpixel() to the newer load() and pixel access object indexing. However the following loop still takes around 2.5 seconds to run for an image of around 720p resolution:

```
def colorclose(Cb_p, Cr_p, Cb_key, Cr_key, tola, tolb):
    temp = math.sqrt((Cb_key-Cb_p)**2+(Cr_key-Cr_p)**2)
    if temp < tola:
        return 0.0
    else: 
        if temp < tolb:
            return (temp-tola)/(tolb-tola)
        else:
            return 1.0
```

....

```
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        Y, cb, cr = fg_cbcr_list[x, y]
        mask = colorclose(cb, cr, cb_key, cr_key, tola, tolb)
        mask = 1 - mask
        bgr, bgg, bgb = bg_list[x,y]
        fgr, fgg, fgb = fg_list[x,y]
        pixels[x,y] = (
            (int)(fgr - mask*key_color[0] + mask*bgr),
            (int)(fgg - mask*key_color[1] + mask*bgg),
            (int)(fgb - mask*key_color[2] + mask*bgb))
```

Am I doing anything hugely inefficient here which makes it run so slow? I have seen similar, simpler examples where the loop is replaced by a boolean matrix for instance, but for this case I can't see a way to replace the loop.

The pixels[x,y] assignment seems to take the most amount of time but not knowing Python very well I am unsure of a more efficient way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One small improvement would be to use xrange instead of range

Comment: Thanks this gave it a slight speed increase

Comment: Generally the slow down comes from individual pixel accessing.  Can you vectorize all the computations to reduce the code to a few statements without loops?  Alternatively, which line is responsible for the slow execution speed?  Once you know which line(s) are slowest you can try to change them.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to iterat through your Pixels row-wise since this is the layout used in memory.

So instead of:

```
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
```

use

```
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
```

EDIT: For Example why this is important you can read the numpy documentation about [iterating over an array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html)

> An important thing to be aware of for this iteration is that the order is chosen to match the memory layout of the array instead of using a standard C or Fortran ordering. This is done for access efficiency, reflecting the idea that by default one simply wants to visit each element without concern for a particular ordering. We can see this by iterating over the transpose of our previous array, compared to taking a copy of that transpose in C order.

Comment: I don't think this would make a noticeable difference for an interpreted language like python.

Comment: I think it is and other do too, i edited my answer with a link to the numpy documentation as example.

Comment: I had tried this already and it makes no noticeable difference. I am not currently using numpy though, will give it a go converting the image to a numpy array first

Comment: I have tried implementing this using NumPy and it's actually significantly slower than using the PIL pixel access objects. From what I've read NumPy only gives significant benefits if you can completely remove the python loop by vectorizing it. Not sure if I can do that in this case but I'm looking into it.